# Jersey : the resource is not available

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

I tried to execute a simple helloworld as a jersey project but the web service didn't start at all. And I have no idea where is the problem.

My main class is the following :

```
 import javax.ws.rs.GET;
 import javax.ws.rs.Path;
 import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

 @Path("/hello")
 public class HelloWorld {
 @GET
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
 public String getMessage() {
    return "Hello world!";
 }
 }
```

here is my web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

  <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-XMLExample-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>jmu.zak</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-XMLExample-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

and my index.jsp

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>MOXy JAX-RS JSON Provider Example</title>
   <style type="text/css"><!--
   .figure {
   text-align: center;
   margin: 20px
    }
   .cliSample {
   background-color: lightgray
   }
   --></style></head>

  <body>
  <p>A <a href="http://wadl.java.net/#spec">WADL description</a> may be  accessed at the URL:</p>
  <blockquote>
  <code>
  <a  href="http://localhost:8080/webapi/application.wadl">http://localhost:8080/webapi/application.wadl</a>
  </code></blockquote>

   <p>The resource is available at</p>
   <blockquote>
   <code>
   <a href="http://localhost:8080/webapi/hello">http://localhost:8080/webapi/hello</a>
   </code>
  </blockquote>
  </body>
  </html>
```

As you cas see, the exemple is very very trivial. It's why I'm so frustrated that my web service never started...

thank you in advance if you help me to fix that, you'll save my life

Comment: Are you deploying this to a server? What HTTP status does it return when you call the API ?

Comment: There are so many possible causes here.  What web server are you using (Tomcat, Glassfish, etc.)?  Does your server log show you any error?  What happens when you try to access the GET resource from your browser?

Comment: I'm using tomcat. When I try to access to localhost:8080/webapi it works but when I try to acces localhost:8080/webapi/hello I got nothing in the log!!! The browser just show me a HTTP Status 404 error message and that "The requested resource (/webapi/hello) is not available"

Comment: Show us your `web.xml` file.  When you say that `http://localhost:8080/webapi` "works," what do you mean by that?

Comment: I added my web.xml and index.jsp to this post

Comment: Try Changing your servlet mapping as below
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-XMLExample-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: It's what I have initially but it still doesn't work for me

Comment: Add a new class to your project and extend ServletContextListener. In overridden contextInitialized() method print something and add the class as a listner in web.xml like '<listener>
  <listener-class>package.NewClassName</listener-class>
 </listener>', see if it is printed when you deploy your project. If not then you servlet itself is not created.

Answer (score 1):

You miss to add an Application subclass

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("api")
public class RestApplication extends Application{

}
```

With this example you can retrieve your resource from http://localhost:8080/webapi/api/hello

Comment: You should request on http://localhost:8080/webapi/api/hello or change the annotation value in '@ApplicationPath("/")' to maintain http://localhost:8080/webapi/hello

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand you well. When you talk about this RestApplication class, does it mean that I had to create this class? (and then, I will have two classes in my programm : the helloWorld.java and RestApplication.java. I am newbi in web developmen and it's not that obvious for me. thx for your comprehension :)

Comment: Yes, add this class. There are multiple ways to deploy a JAX-RS application. With Servlet3.x annotations, with web.xml, with both... You should take a look to the documentation to better understand https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet.3

Comment: I swear that I didn't still work for me. I think that I will simply give up and try to use another framework than jersey :)

Comment: Just try to include the Application subclass and remove web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I think the URL you are trying is missing the Context Path. Every web application has a context path, so if you find out what your context path is, you should then use this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/<your context path>/webapi/hello
```